# Horde Webmail HTML signature internet explorer

Tags: html, webmail, horde

How can I use HTML signature in Horde webmail. I can see the there is option "Switch to HTML composition" in firfox when I compose new message. But I don't see it in Internet Explorer and Chrome. I want to use my HTML signature embeded (by default) whenever I compose new message in all browser.

Any Solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Horde ticket system](http://bugs.horde.org/ticket/1406), it appears that there is no official support for HTML signatures in Horde Webmail.

It is partially implemented via Stationery, and others have suggested just creating a Draft in HTML Composition mode, inserting your Sig there, and just duplicating the Draft whenever you send an e-mail.

Beyond that, it may be something you can code yourself if you have access to the source.

Comment: yes stationery was the only option which i came up with. However composing a new message in html is not supported by all browsers. So it seems like, there is no feasible solution for this problem.

Comment: Further to jnpcl - if you are using a server management system like Plesk, changing the config files to "hack" this in (as I have) will simply result in it randomly disappearing again some day, when Plesk does an update and replaces all of your changes. If you do go that route, make a backup of the new and old files, as you change them!